# Help with ASP.NET MVC 2 Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, iis-6

Is there any reason why a route would be properly mapped in one environment and not another? I am deploying the exact same routing information from my local development server to a production server, and the routes are not being evaluated the same.

I have downloaded Phil Haack's [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), and it is confirming that the routes are matching locally, but not in production.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

UPDATE: I didn't include many details above. The production server is IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. All my routes were working except for one that I was using as a custom image handler. The route I specified was mapping to a URL that ended with ".png"

I found that this was the problem with IIS 6 since it was  not handing off the ".png" request off to ASP.NET. I added a wildcard mapping to the site and that fixed the problem.

I apologize for not having put more details before. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Details, please? Being specific might get you an answer.

Comment: Please post your routes and some example URLs that result in this pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things at work. As you mentioned, IIS 6 doesn't hand off requests that aren't mapped to the ASPNET_ISAPI.dll. A wildcard mapping fixes that problem.

The other potential issue is that by default, routing doesn't route files that exist on disk. So if you make a request for a physical .png file, it won't get routed.

Comment: you are right. I came to find this out earlier this week and was able to make the necessary adjustments to IIS. Everything seems to be working now. Thanks for the input.